# Ag-grid not scrolling vertically down

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

using ag-grid version 9.1.0

```
gridOptions = {
    enableColResize: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    suppressMenuHide: true,
    rowBuffer : 200,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: Columns,
    onRowClicked: onRowClicked,
    getRowStyle: getRowStyle,
    onGridReady: function(event) { 
        vm.gridOptions.api.ensureIndexVisible(scrollId, null);
        //vm.gridOptions.api.ensureColumnVisible(scrollId);
    }
};
```

This is  grid initialization. onGridReady , I call this ensureIndexVisible but when i open the grid , its not scrolling down automatically. It just shows the top part and doesn't scroll. Ensured that the scrollId exists. How to make it scroll automatically?